# Vue and webpack warning

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I would like use Vue with webpack. I've install all dependencies, but i've warning after compilation :

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.  (found in
>   )

My app.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import test from './components/cartItem.vue'; // Simple <template> with string

new Vue({
  el: '#js-cart-list'
});
```

My package.json :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.14.3",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^3.18.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "goog-webfont-dl": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "vue-loader": "^11.3.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.6",
    "webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "family.scss": "^1.0.8",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "motion-ui": "^1.1.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.2.6"
  }
```

It's my first time using vue with webpack, anyone have idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please edit your question to include your `webpack.config.js` - that's almost certainly where the issue lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this to your webpack config file:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```

Components pre-compiled, you should also put all of them in *.vue files.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215

Comment: looks like we can also rename a "main.js" file into .vue